# How to provide ENV variable from k8s to a python app during the docker run

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have a docker file in which I am hardcoding the env variables for now as it gets injected in the app during the build process. Now, I want to inject those during the runtime when the application gets ran in the k8s pod. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354568/pip-install-failing-on-kubernetes-pod) but its not working. Below is my docker file. Its my first time using serious python and am not sure how to fix it.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

#ENV USE_DB="True" \
#   DB_USERNAME= \
#   DB_HOST= \
#   DB_PASSWORD= \
#   DB_DB=sth
RUN pip3 install dist/app_search*.whl && \
    semanticsearch-preprocess

FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /opt/srv

COPY --from=build /app/dist/app_search*.whl /opt/srv/

COPY --from=build /tmp/projects* /opt/srv/

# set environment variables to /opt/srv
ENV DICT_FILE="/opt/srv/projects.dict" \
    MODEL_FILE="/opt/srv/projects.model.cpickle" \
    INDEX_FILE="/opt/srv/projects.index" \
    EXTERNAL_INDEX_FILE="/opt/srv/projects.mm.metadata.cpickle"


RUN pip3 install waitress && \
    pip3 install app_search*.whl

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "waitress-serve" ]

CMD [ "--call", "app_search.app:main" ]
```

Comment: if you want to inject K8s --> pod you will need to specify these in your K8s deployment yaml files

Comment: Did you see [k8s docs: define-environment-variable-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) ?

Answer (score 0):

First Create k8s configmap or k8s secret(better for sensitive data) in your cluster.
Then read these values in k8s deployment yaml as env variables for pod.

official Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Eg. Create secret yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
    username: "abc-user"
    password: "pwd-here"
```

Deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: DB_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      - name: DB_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass env variables to k8s pod with pod spec field: `env`.

Look a the following example from k8s docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

Also take a look at k8s documentaion for more information:

- [k8s api spec reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#envvar-v1-core)
- [defining environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)
- [using secrets as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)